# Can't represent a size of 214748364 in Constraints

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout

I just created a simple Composable and wished to render it using a `Layout`, but while implementing the solution, I stumbled upon this error in the measurement phase.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't represent a size of 214748364 in Constraints
        at androidx.compose.ui.unit.Constraints$Companion.bitsNeedForSize(Constraints.kt:408)
        at androidx.compose.ui.unit.Constraints$Companion.createConstraints-Zbe2FdA$ui_unit_release(Constraints.kt:368)
        at androidx.compose.ui.unit.ConstraintsKt.Constraints(Constraints.kt:438)
        at androidx.compose.ui.unit.ConstraintsKt.Constraints$default(Constraints.kt:423)
        at com.gmarsk.aiare.MainActivity$InstructionsScreen$DisplayCard$1.measure-3p2s80s(MainActivity.kt:514)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(InnerPlaceable.kt:54)
```

This was when I tried this

```
val sampleComposable = measurables[1].measure(
                Constraints(
                    minHeight = constraints.maxHeight * 7 / 10,
                )
            )
```

Anyone stumble upon this before? What's the solution if it is not a bug, in which case please let me know.

Now, the issue here I think is the fact that I am nesting two `Layout` Composables,

```
Layout(
content = {
 Dummy1()
 Dummy2()
 NestedLayoutComposable() // It contains a Layout Composable itself
}{ measurables, constraints ->
 val nlc = measurables[2].measure(
  Constraints(
   minHeight = constraints.maxHeight * 7/10
  )
 )
 layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight){
  nls.place(0, 0)
 }
}
)
```

Where The nestedLayoutComposable again has a Layout and that is where the crash occurs, it is at this line

```
            Layout(
                content = {
                    Text(text = "Random")
                    Box {
                        Image(painter = AppUtils.getRandomImagePainter(), contentDescription = "")
                    }
                }
            ) { measurables, constraints ->
                val text = measurables[0].measure(constraints)
/*This line -->*/   val image = measurables[1].measure(
                    Constraints(
                        maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth * 90 / 100,
                        minHeight = constraints.maxHeight * 7 / 10
                    )
                )

                layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
                    instruction.place(
                        (constraints.maxWidth - instruction.width) / 2,
                        0
                    )
                    illustration.place(
                        (constraints.maxWidth - illustration.width) / 2,
                        illustration.height / 2
                    )
                }
            }
```

So I know that the issue is with the `Layout` Composable being nested within one another but that still doesn't explain WHY the error occurs, and HOW to resolve it, and so those are the prime queries of this post, and that is what I expect the answers to include, thank you.

Comment: Interesting....  the only hint I can give is.....   It looks like the tool is using signed 32 bit numbers instead of unsigned.  In the function call giving you grief consider scaling by 9/10 instead of 90/100 (the multiply by 90 may be aggravating an overflow).

Comment: @Mark what exactly am I to take away from this?

Comment: @J.R.Schweitzer I tried that but it still gives the same error which actually makes sense, since even if the constraints "store" the numbers in a representation of their own, the assignment (or storage) phase would not be triggered till the calculation is complete, which means that I can literally deal in numbers ranging to billions and it would still never matter if by the end I have reasonable values.

Comment: It works every time, the problem seems to be because of nesting it. So, I'm pretty sure the measurement method is not the issue, sir. Thanks for the input though, appreciate it.

Comment: I seem to be having a similar issue. My layout measurements work fine when they're 1-2 deep, but anything other than that I get `Can't represent a size of 214748364 in Constraints` as well. Did you get anywhere with this by any chance? @MARSK

Comment: I came across this when adding a `ComposeView` inside a layout contained by a `NestedScrollView`. The composable view started with a `Column` - my guess is the scrollable column was interacting with the scrollable container - of that the scrollable container has an infinite size, resulting in this error we both saw.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier did you make any fix for this issue? Seems like I'm having the same error.

Comment: No I went with my guess and removed that scrollable `Column` from the layout.

Comment: I get this error when adding a `verticalScroll` modifier to a non-nested `VerticalScollbar`, which is probably a stupid thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

In my case similar crash was caused by scrollable Column inside another scrollable Column. Check if you do not have such a case in your compose hierarchy.

Comment: While it does provide a correlation between scrollable columns and the problem, it does not, unfortunately, provide a solution or a workaround to the problem. If a design requires scrollable columns, it would not be ideal to change the design because it is, in fact, possible to nest scrollables in Compose.

Answer (score 4):

In your case it's because you can't measure anything with multipliers of `Constraints.Infinity`. Because in source code of createConstraints function

```
 internal fun createConstraints(
        minWidth: Int,
        maxWidth: Int,
        minHeight: Int,
        maxHeight: Int
    ): Constraints {

        //  Because of this check and bitsNeedForSize
      
        val heightVal = if (maxHeight == Infinity) minHeight else maxHeight
        val heightBits = bitsNeedForSize(heightVal)

        val widthVal = if (maxWidth == Infinity) minWidth else maxWidth
        val widthBits = bitsNeedForSize(widthVal)
}
```

converts `heightVal` to 0 when passed height is Constraints.Infinity when you modify it you send a value to `bitsNeedForSize` that overflows maxrange and it crashes with

```
    private fun bitsNeedForSize(size: Int): Int {
        return when {
            size < MaxNonFocusMask -> MaxNonFocusBits
            size < MinNonFocusMask -> MinNonFocusBits
            size < MinFocusMask -> MinFocusBits
            size < MaxFocusMask -> MaxFocusBits
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException(
                "Can't represent a size of $size in " +
                    "Constraints"
            )
        }
    }
```

Simple check should be whether the dimension you use is Constraints.Infinity using hasBoundedHeight or constraints.min/maxHieght == Constraints.Infinity

Also another check should be for min constraints not being bigger than maxConstraints so

```
val wrappedConstraints = constraints.copy(
    minHeight = if (constraints.hasBoundedHeight)
        (constraints.maxHeight * 7 / 10).coerceAtMost(constraints.maxHeight)
    else 0,

)
```

using such a Constraints to measure your content Composables won't crash.

Also to set your custom layout height if it has a Modifier.fillMaxHeight() or Modifier.height(100) by checking hasFixedHeight and not a infinite with hasBoundedHeight

```
  val contentHeight = // This some height you get with max, sum or your logic

  val totalHeight = if(hasBoundedHeight && hasFixedHeight){
        constraints.maxHeight
    }else {
        contentHeight.coerceIn(constraints.minHeight.toFloat(), constraints.maxHeight.toFloat())
    }
```

When it doesn't have a size Modifier or a Modifier with `Modifier.height(min=0.dp, max=500.dp)`

you say let this Composable as big as content but within range of Constraints from size Modifier.

This check also makes sure your Composable do not crash when intrinsic height modifier is assigned.

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't represent a size of 2147483647 in Constraints
> ```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else that comes across this, the problems is that scrollable views set maxHeight to `Constraints.Infinity`, which is represented as `Int.MAX_VALUE`. So if your layout assumes a bounded height, it's going to overflow the int value.

Answer (score 2):

This basically happens when you jam much more than the composable has room for to display.

I have reproduced it using a very long String for a List item

Comment: Wow, this answer helped me the most! For me, I was placing very long text inside a fixed-size Box.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I tried to use a `Slider` inside a `Column` that had `Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Min)`, no matter whether the column is its direct parent or not. Though the exception disappears  when I use another overload of the slider where you provide a lambda to the `thumb` parameter but this time the slider doesn't have a thumb. The exception also disappears when I specify a fixed width on the slider.

It's a bug.

Edit: fixed, just needed to update libs.

Edit 2: the libraries were:

- `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom`, updated from 1.8.0 to 1.9.0
- `androidx.compose:compose-bom`, updated from 2022.10.00 to 2023.06.01 and the respective `androidTestImplementation` though I don't think the latter was necessary since I didn't write tests

The minimum SDK version was 31

Comment: Can you provide the package you had to update to fix this bug? And maybe the minimum version?